# what means 'add_run' in python-pptx?

Tags: python

```
p = text_frame.paragraphs[0]
p.text = paragraph_strs[0]
p.alignment = PP_ALIGN.LEFT
run = p.add_run()
run.text = 'Spam, eggs, and spam'
```

I don`t know 'add_run' means, thank you for help!

Comment: Maybe help you [here](https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/412) `Help removing leading blank line before paragraph.runs text within table cells`

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing the information from this webpage :
https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html

At this section :
Only ***runs*** can actually contain text. Assigning a string to the .text attribute on a shape, text frame, or paragraph ***is a shortcut method*** for placing text in a run contained by those objects. The following two snippets produce the same result:

```html
shape.text = 'foobar'

# is equivalent to ...

text_frame = shape.text_frame
text_frame.clear()
p = text_frame.paragraphs[0]
run = p.add_run()
run.text = 'foobar'
```